# What is the best solution for remote desktop / visual support?

Tags: remote-desktop

We are currently investigating different remote-desktop support solutions to help our clients if they have any problems with our software and I would like some input on the best solutions out there.

We have the following needs / wishes:

- Cross platform
- Preferrably no installation on the user-end
- Should penetrate firewalls and not be bothered by antivirus stuff.
- Should leave no residu behind after support.

I know of VNC, logmeinrescue.com, dameware remote control, msn remote desktop and many others, but which one is the best?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would also suggest [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com), there is a free version and a commercial one that you can rebrand with your logo to redistribute to your clients. It does require (non administrative) install but works also behind firewalls.

Answer (score 2):

[Copilot](https://www.copilot.com/)

Answer (score 2):

We use UltraVnc SC (Single Click), see here: 
http://www.uvnc.com/addons/singleclick.html

Your client needs only download a small file from your helpdesk and run it. Then your helpdesk can control the client's desktop. The small file will uninstall itself after closing the session. The requirement is your UltraVNC should be run in listen mode.

Comment: UltraVNC doesn't traverse routers correct? You'd need to have everything on the same network or open a port in the router of the remote location.

Comment: No, UltraVNC **SC** is just as the answer describes. The problem/requirement indeed lies with having to use listen mode over UltraVNC on the **helpdesk's** side. It can be avoided by using UltraVNC's 3 free repeaters. But they're unreliable so my solution was to develop a program that opens ports via UPnP (using the free [MiniUPnP](http://miniupnp.free.fr) if needed) and only then launches UltraVNC.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/)!
Especially because it's very easy for the 'other side'.
No complicated skills required. Just install and run it. Easy to explain over the phone while immediatly asking for their 'code'.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`CoPilot`](https://www.copilot.com/).

Answer (score 1):

[TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/) has been a great help to me so far but it's only available on Windows and Mac. No Linux support unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I personally feel that UltraVNC is the best support tool for Windows boxes, especially since the end user can see what you're doing as you're doing it.  Very good for training purposes as well.

RDP is neat, but I find it very frusting to use, unless on high-bandwidth or bandwidth stable machines.  Port forwarding can also be a pain if the routing hardware is not great at the end users endpoint.  You also need to worry about user permissions and enabling RDP as well, which if you need to do in 3rd person, can be tricky.

UltraVNC (like the other VNC clients) has a cool "Listening Host" which allows you to still VNC into a VNC server if the server's endpoint is not a direct connection to the net.  This can be very useful.  I've worked in the financial services sector, and we use VNC in this capacity and have never had any issue both installing it enmasse and have never had a security breach.

SSH is also an option, and with OpenSSH you can use it on windows (using cygwin) but this isn't always suitable.

In the end, I think VNC is possibly your best bet.

Comment: These are not the kind of solutions you can use for anyone that needs your support. This is more for remote management of servers.

Comment: True, please see [the answer of UltraVNC SC instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/464793/4829915).

Answer (score 1):

I've had very good experiences with [CrossLoop](http://www.crossloop.com/). It's free and allows you to setup a connection within 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I use logmein.com quite a bit which works very well but it does have a full client installation.  However it is available at any point and once installed does not require user to allow remote connection (which may or may not be ok with your customers).

Given your requirements, I think CoPilot is probably your only option, although you will require client interaction - they need to download and run an executable, but its very straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I have had good experience with the remote control of [NTRSupport](http://www.ntrglobal.com/ntrsupport/en-US/home-NTRsupport.asp). Quite easy to use with no installation required.

I also used and/or use the following software that does not cover all your requirements:

- Timbuktu Pro - Bad performance, few features, can't recommend it nowadays.
- UltraVNC - Works, but I remember some problems with clipboard and file transfer support.
- PCAnywhere - Works, but the performance was never satisfying, Awkward clipboard handling.
- RDP - Great for Windows machines but can be problematic when it is not clear whether you have to use the console session or not. Sometimes, you disconnect a server session just by accident.

Answer (score 0):

For windows only: [Crossloop](http://www.crossloop.com)